# Failed to validate installed provider after upgrade to Terraform v0.13.4

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I've recently upgraded my Terraform to v0.13.4 and I'm now having an issue initiating my workspace(s).

```
- terraform.io/builtin/terraform is built in to Terraform
- Using previously-installed hashicorp/aws v3.9.0
- Using previously-installed hashicorp/archive v1.3.0

Error: Failed to validate installed provider

Validating provider hashicorp/archive v1.3.0 failed: provider binary not
found: could not find executable file starting with terraform-provider-archive
```

I've tried to point the required provider here:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    archive = {
      source = "hashicorp/archive"
      version = "1.3.0"
    }
    aws = {
      region                  = "us-east-2"
      #profile                 = "arm-sandbox"
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Because the output includes the message "Using previously-installed hashicorp/archive", I suspect you somehow have a corrupted version of that provider in the provider cache in your working directory. If so, removing the `.terraform` directory (where Terraform caches those) and then re-running `terraform init` may fix it, or may at least give you some better feedback on why the package is invalid.

Comment: This is not directly related to your question but I also want to note that the `region` and `profile` arguments don't belong in that location; they belong in [a `provider "aws"` block](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/providers.html) elsewhere in your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the previously installed version (1.3.0) of the `archive` provider is either not correctly supported in Terraform 0.13+, or is either installed incorrectly or potentially corrupt.

Consider updating to the latest version of the provider which will also subsequently download the newest version. Providers are handled differently in 0.13+ compared to previous versions, so it's a good idea to run `terraform upgrade0.13` on your workspace to ensure everything is converted and formatted correctly for Terraform 0.13+.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    archive = {
      source  = "hashicorp/archive"
      version = "2.1.0"
    }
  }
}
```

---

Also as @martin-atkins correctly pointed out, the aws `region` can't be specified inside the `required_providers` block, but should be in the provider block:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "3.37.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-2"
}
```